# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found IIS is not used

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

My WCF Service is self-hosted. IIS is not used. 
Getting error

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
```

Please advise.

```
Service.cs

    public string SayComment(string Message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" \n SayComment Message Captured : " + Message);
        return "    I commenting on you     \n  \n MessageVersion on this Server \n " + MessageVersion.Default.ToString();
    } 

IService.cs
    [OperationContract]
    string SayComment(string Message);
```

Call service on browser : http://localhost:8001/HomServer
On Client side, i used WebRequest and WebResponse

```
WebRequest MOD_webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8001/HomServer"); 
        MOD_webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        MOD_webRequest.Method = "POST";

 MOD_webResponse = MOD_webRequest.GetResponse();
```

is generating ERROR : [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.], Instead of capturing a response.

Comment: Some code snippets of service and client will be helpful.

Comment: Post the hosting and client code. It's impossible to say without that. For all we know, you simply never started the host.

Comment: The request is the client code 
WebRequest MOD_webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8001/HomServer"); 
        MOD_webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        MOD_webRequest.Method = "POST";

 MOD_webResponse = MOD_webRequest.GetResponse();